# How to fix 'hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testFunc.call() '

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I am trying to call a function using shared library in Jenkins. The shared library groovy file exists in the /vars folder of a repository.

I have tried othernames for the shared library file. I tried calling it also using testFunc.call(), testFunc, testFunc()

testFunc.groovy

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.*
import java.net.URL
def coveragepercentage
def testFunc(){

    def param = "${env:TestCoverage}"
    echo param
    def paramInt = param as int
    echo "Integer "+ paramInt
    def jsondata = readFile(file:'./target/site/munit/coverage/munit-coverage.json')
           def data = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsondata)
           coveragepercentage = data.coverage
           echo "${coveragepercentage}"

        if(coveragepercentage > paramInt){
           println("This value is smaller")
           sh "exit 1"
           currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
}
```

Jenkinsfile that uses the above shared librabry

```
@Library('shared-lib2') _
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.*
import java.net.URL
pipeline{
  agent any
    tools {
      maven 'Maven'
      jdk  'JAVA'
        }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'config', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML')]) {
                sh "mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML clean package"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('test function'){
            steps{
                script{
                testFunc()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('MUnit Test Report') {
               steps{
                script {
                  publishHTML(target:[allowMissing: false,alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,keepAll: true,reportDir: 'target/site/munit/coverage',reportFiles: 'summary.html',reportName: 'MUnit Test Report',reportTitles: 'MUnit Test Coverage Report'])
                }
                  }
            }   
    }
```

Error: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testFunc.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Answer (score 4):

And in my case I had

```
call() {
```

while it should be

```
def call() {
```

Shame.

Answer (score 2):

In your `testFunc.groovy`, you need to rename the function from `testFunc` into `call()`.

After these changes, it will be possible to call your function as declarative step.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my groovy and it worked for me. Dont know if this helps!

**Solution**

```
def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    pipeline{
        //your code
    }
}
```